# Duplicate table fields vs indexing only

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a huge and very busy table (few thousands INSERT / second). The table stores loginlogs, it has a bigint ID which is not generated by MySQL but rather by pseudorandom generator on MySQL client.

Simply put, the table has `loginlog_id, client_id, tons,of,other,columns,with,details,about,session....`

I have few indexes on this table such as `PRIMARY_KEY(loginlog_id)` and `INDEX(client_id)`

In some other part of our system I need to fetch client_id based on loginlog_id. This does not happen that often (just few hundreds `SELECT client_id FROM loginlogs WHERE loginlog_id=XXXXXX` / second). Table loginlogs is read by various other scripts now and then, and always various columns are needed. But the most frequent call to read is for sure the above mentioned get client_id by loginlog_id.

My question is: should I create another table loginlogs_clientids and duplicate loginlog_id, client_id in there (this means another few thousands INSERTS, as for every loginlogs INSERT I get this new one). Or should I be happy with InnoDB handling my lookups by PRIMARY KEY efficiently.

We have tons of RAM (128GB, most of which is used by MySQL). Load of MySQL is between 40% and 350% CPU (we have 12 core CPU). When I tried to use the new table, I did not see any difference. But I am asking for the future, if our usage grows even more, what is the suggested approach? Duplicate or index?

Thanks!

Comment: It's rarely appropriate to put redundant data in the database. It's something you might do if joins cause performance problems that can't be resolved some other way.

Comment: Such high CPU implies poor indexing and/or poor formulation of queries.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT ...`

Comment: Please also post A) SHOW INDEX FROM table_name; and EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); so we can see what the Optimizer is doing with your request.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Looking up table data for a single row using the primary key is extremely efficient, and will take the same time for both tables.

Exceptions to that might be very large row sizes (e.g. 8KB+), and `client_id` is e.g. a varchar that is stored off-page, in which case you might need to read an additional data block, which at least theoretically could cost you some milliseconds.

Even if this strategy would have an advantage, you would not actually do it by creating a new table, but by adding an index `(loginlog_id, client_id)` to your original table. InnoDB stores everything, including the actual data, in an index structure, so that adding an index is basically the same as adding a new table with the same columns, but without (you) having the problem of synchronizing those two "tables".

Having a structure with a smaller row size can have some advantages for ranged scans, e.g. MySQL will evaluate `select count(*) from tablename` using the smallest index of the table, as it has to read less bytes. You already have such a small index (on `client_id`), so even in that regard, adding such an additonal table/index shouldn't have an effect. If you have any range scan on the primary key (which is probably unlikely for pseudorandom data), you may want to consider this though, or keep it in mind for cases when you have.